# How to explain NoClassDefFoundError in this situation?

Tags: java, javac, noclassdeffounderror

I'm very new to Java, just want run `javac` and `java` from commandline.

My current directory contents is:

```
hmank ~/c/J/naive » ls
HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.java
```

The code in `HelloWorld.java` is:

```
hmank ~/c/J/naive » cat HelloWorld.java 
package com.imshuai.javalinux;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

---

I know I should first run `javac -d . HelloWorld.java` then run `java com.imshuai.javalinux.HelloWorld`.

**But**, I want to see what will happen if I run `javac HelloWorld.java` and `java HelloWorld` directly!

The result is `javac` could compile `HelloWorld.java`, but when run `java HelloWorld` I get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/imshuai/javalinux/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld)
```

I'm confused by `NoClassDefFoundError`, cause I defined the `HelloWorld` in current directory. And `jvm` must found the `HelloWorld.class` and load it otherwise `jvm` can't no information about `com/imshuai/javalinux/HelloWorld`.

In fact, if I do

```
javac -d . HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

I got the same `NoClassDefFoundError` though `HelloWorld.class` in both right and wrong place.

---

In my opinion, in the above wrong situation, `jvm` should report a `class location not match package` error, cause `jvm` found the class and there is no a right location to place `HelloWorld.class` to make `java HelloWorld` run success.

---

What's more, could you please tell me why `jvm` decided to report a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, and what's the meaning of `wrong name: HelloWorld`?

Comment: Try java -cp . HelloWorld

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`, `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/imshuai/javalinux/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld)`. So the meaning is you provide a wrong class name `HelloWorld`, what jvm need is `com/imshuai/javalinux/HelloWorld`. So wrong name `HelloWorld` will not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the package organization since you are specifying `package com.imshuai.javalinux` but lack the proper folder structure.

You should arrange your classes in folders according to the package declaration.

The `-d .` in the `javac` command makes it work because it creates the folder structure of the packages instead of putting all the `.class` files on the root directory.

So, if you run `java com/imshuai/javalinux/HelloWorld`the output is `Hello, World!` and the program works.

Another solution would be to add that folder to the java classpath.